# How can I send Email in Laravel command instead of controller

Tags: php, laravel, cron, command, html-email

I'm working on a project using Laravel where I want to be able to send an email when it is scheduled to send.

So far I've only found solutions to send a mail through a Route but I want to be able to send the mail when cron activates my self made command. I've already made a view of the mail that should be sent and made a page sendMail with `php artisan make:mail sendMail` that returns the mail view.

sendMail.php

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Mail;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
 use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
 use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class sendMail extends Mailable
 { 
     use Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $winnersposts = DB::select('select post_id from winners group by post_id');
    $posts = DB::select('select * from posts ');

    $this->winnerposts =$winnersposts;
    $this->posts=$posts;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{

    return $this ->from('ivanrompa@gmail.com')
                 ->view('emails.template');
}
```

}

mailAdmin.php

```
public function handle()
{

}
```

My command handle is still empty but I previously tried to implement to logic from my controller above in my command but it didn't work.

Am I writing the wrong code and is that the reason it just doesn't work or should I approach it in a different way? It is maybe good to know that I am still learning Laravel and I have never sent an email before through code. Any tips or solutions are welcome.

Comment: can you elaborate on "it didn't work" more and where are you making the call to send this mailable?

Comment: Have you read [Sending Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#sending-mail) from the manual?

Comment: I copied all the logic from sendMail in to my mailAdmin command also all of the imports. when running ``php artisan do:mailadmin`` it gave me this error -->  Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'App\Mail\Command' not found.

Comment: I don't think I made a call to send the mailable? how would I have to format this call?

Comment: "_how would I have to format this call?_" So you haven't read [Sending Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#sending-mail) from the manual

Comment: That error is related to importing something wrong, can you show that handle code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have set your email configuration correctly. 
Add this in your `mailAdmin.php`

```
use Mail;
use App\Mail\sendMail

public function handle()
{
  Mail::to('recipient@gmail.com')->send(new sendMail);
}
```

Then run the command

Comment: I did this and it works. I have a side question if I make changes to my .env file. Do I need to do something extra to push the changes through? Because I made a mistake with MAIL_HOST and I corrected it but when I run `` php artisan do:mailadmin `` I get this error `` ?[41;1m Swift_TransportException ?[49;22m : ?[33mConnection could not be established with host ivanrompa@gmail.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Er is een onherstelbare fout opgetreden tijdens het zoeken in de database.  #0]?[39m `` and in this error I can see that the value of host is still the old value.

Comment: @imkeVr try `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: yes thank you that worked but I guess I didn't configure it the right way. It still gives me an error.  `  ?[41;1m Swift_TransportException ?[49;22m : ?[33mConnection could not be established with host smtp.googlemail.com [ #0]?[39m`

Comment: if i am not mistaken i think it should be `smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp  ,
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com  ,
MAIL_PORT=465  ,
MAIL_USERNAME=ivanrompa@gmail.com  ,
MAIL_PASSWORD=***** ,
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl   ,  I changed it and configuered it to this but still the same error? Can't seem to find my mistake

Comment: Everytime when you change the `.env` file run the commands i mentioned previously. If it still doesn't work try to change the `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl` to `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`

Comment: Okay, I changed it and it seemed to work but eventually, it gives me a timed out error and when I want to start up my project with ``php artisan serve`` I get a 500 server error.

Comment: Any more details?

Comment: I can only provide the error of `php artisan do:mailadmin` -> ` ?[41;1m Swift_TransportException ?[49;22m : ?[33mConnection to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:465 Timed Out?[39m` for the 500 server error I found a solution

Comment: @imkeVr Something's wrong with your mail configuration. My guess is the encryption.